# Cannot connect to Jenkins docker container running inside Vagrant on Mac

Tags: jenkins, docker, vagrant

I am running Vagrant on Mac - to spin out an Ubuntu VM. Docker is installed on the Ubuntu VM.

I pulled down the Jenkins container using : `docker pull jenkins` and started it by saying : `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name=jenkins-master jenkins`.

However,I am unable to connect to Jenkins from the browser on port 8080. I tried reaching Jenkins from browser using the following : 
1. http://IP1:8080 where IP1 is the value returned by the command `docker inspect <container_name>`.
2. http://IP2:8080 where IP2 is the eth0 value returned by the command 'ifconfig' inside the ubuntu VM.

Comment: Not directly helpful for your situation, but FYI, this sort of thing is a lot easier using [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/), which would bridge this stuff together for you (then you can just bind ports and they'll show up on localhost - easy). Also eliminates the need to have Vagrant/virtualbox or manage an Ubuntu box, all just to get Docker.

Comment: You tell it to start with mapping port 8080 to the host port 8080. However when you run this inside vagrant (and I guess virtual box) you have to [forward a port](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) from your host to the Ubuntu vm, then you can access it in your browser at http://localhost:<the port you chose>/. So basically the `port` option in the docker command tells docker to expose a port on the docker container and map it to a specific port on the host. In your case you are exposing port 8080 in the docker container an mapping it to port 8080 on the Ubuntu vm

Comment: Alright @Rik's response helped with Jenkins access from the browser. I was able to get to the Getting Started Jenkins page after setting up port forwarding in Vagrantfile.

Comment: Also, I agree with what @DanLowe says, now. I set out with the intent that using Vagrant on Mac, I would be able to fully replicate an Ubuntu VM with Docker environment. While it is mostly similar, I, now, realize that there are quiet a few differences.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to access the jenkins on your VM machine than try:

`localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080`

If you are accessing from host machine than change your vagrant config as:

`Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
end`

and again try :
`localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: you can inspect your container using docker exec -it jenkins-master /bin/bash

Answer (score 1):

You need double port forwarding here, you do the port forwarding of Vagrant network interface to docker container network interface ('-p 8080:8080'), but miss the port forwarding of your Mac network interface to vagrant machine.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
end
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html

Answer (score 0):

if your docker and jenkins are installed in VM. first run to check what is the name of your docker container. if any remove all by $docker rm container_name.

Then run below command to run jenkins:

$vagrant ssh.  it will let u to get inside the VM. Then

$ docker run  -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000  --name myjenkins jenkinsci/jenkins( your jenkins image name installed).

Boom.